# Detect scene change with no audio together using FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, scene, android-ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I want to detect scene change with no audio using ffmpeg in window. I want a single command to detect at which point scene changed as well as no audio is there.

Comment: From the question it is not clear, what you actually want.  What exactly do you mean by scene change?  Do you want to know a frame number?  What is the relation with audio?

Comment: Actually i want to get diiferent parts in a running video. So, to differentiate the parts in a video. I am thinking of fetching scene chnage and audio silence together as fade in and fade out

Answer (score 0):

May be you can check how [motion](https://motion-project.github.io/) is doing this.

Motion is a camera monitor which detect activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the command:

```
ffmpeg inputvideo.mp4 -filter_complex "select='gt(scene,0.3)',metadata=print:file=time.txt" -vsync vfr img%03d.png
```

This will save just the relevant information in the time.txt file like below:

```
frame:0    pts:108859  pts_time:1.20954
lavfi.scene_score=0.436456
frame:1    pts:285285  pts_time:3.16983
lavfi.scene_score=0.444537
frame:2    pts:487987  pts_time:5.42208
lavfi.scene_score=0.494256
frame:3    pts:904654  pts_time:10.0517
lavfi.scene_score=0.462327
frame:4    pts:2533781 pts_time:28.1531
lavfi.scene_score=0.460413
frame:5    pts:2668916 pts_time:29.6546
lavfi.scene_score=0.432326
```

The frame is the serial number of the detected shot change from the starting. Also, choose your threshold value (here 0.3) appropriately for your use case to get correct outputs